# Compress old emails with dovecot

Tags: email, dovecot, compression, gzip

How can I configure dovecot to compress/archive old emails (say 6 months old) with the users still being able to read them, to save some precious space on the server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The configuration to compress emails is a two step process:

1. We need to configure dovecot to be able to read compressed emails
2. We need to setup a cronjob to compress emails

### Dovecot configuration

Create a configuration file for dovecot to enable the zlib plugin

Dovecot configuration files are usually found in `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/`

You can create a file named `35-zlib.conf` in this directory with this content

```
# Enable Zlib for imap
protocol imap {
  mail_plugins = $mail_plugins zlib
}
# Enable Zlib for pop3
protocol pop3 {
  mail_plugins = $mail_plugins zlib
}
# Increase memory allowed for imap as it costs more to read compressed files
service imap {
  vsz_limit = 1024MB
}
```

Make sure your configuration is correct with `doveconf -n`, then restart dovecot using `service dovecot restart`

### Daily cronjob

Next we need to run a script every day to compress emails that are older than 6 months

Hopefully this can be done with a *[verbose]* find command

In `/etc/cron.daily/` create a file, let's call it `archive-email`

Write this script in it

```
#!/bin/bash
find /var/qmail/mailnames -mtime +182 -type f -regex ".*\.$HOSTNAME,.*S=.*,[a-yA-Y]*" ! -name "*\.gz*" -print0 |
 while read -rd $'\0' FULLPATH
  do
    echo "${FULLPATH}"
    if file "${FULLPATH}" | grep compressed -q; then
      mv "${FULLPATH}" "${FULLPATH}Z" # Already compressed
    else
      BASENAME=$(basename "${FULLPATH}")
      cp -a "${FULLPATH}" "/tmp/${BASENAME}" # Move to tmp
      gzip -f "/tmp/${BASENAME}" # Compress
      if [[ -f ${FULLPATH} ]]; then # Make sure the original file has not been deleted while we were compressing
        mv "/tmp/${BASENAME}.gz" "${FULLPATH}Z" && rm "${FULLPATH}"
      else
        rm "/tmp/${BASENAME}.gz"
        continue
      fi
    fi
    echo "${FULLPATH}" >> /var/log/archived-emails.log
  done
```

Don't forget to run `chmod +x` on the created file to make it executable

> `/var/qmail/mailnames` is usually the root folder in which emails are stored, it may depend on your configuration
>
> The `-mtime +182` modifier allows us to find only files created more than 182
> days ago (basically 6 months), modify it accordingly
>
> With the`-type f -regex ".*\.$HOSTNAME,.*S=.*,[a-yA-Y]*"` modifier, we want to find only email files that don't have the Z flag in them, which are usually named in this format
> `1505740244.M351559P24632.my.domain.com,S=38204,W=40910:2,S`
> More information on the maildir format [here](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailboxFormat/Maildir)
>
> Finally we copy the emails to compress to the `\tmp` dir to avoid conflict while compressing, we run the gzip command on the file and move them again if the file still exists in their original location adding a Z flag in their name to indicate they are compressed so we don't gzip them again and finally remove the original file
>
> This process has been implemented according to the guidelines of the [dovecot wiki](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/zlib_plugin/#compression) but the `maildirlock` utility [has a bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=932253) since v2 that has never been fixed, so I'm not using it, however it's unlikely it will cause issues
>
> We also log all the successfully archived files in `/var/log/archived-emails.log`

You can run the command in your terminal first without exec to make sure you match the correct files

`find /var/qmail/mailnames -mtime +182 -type f -regex ".*\.$HOSTNAME,.*S=.*,[a-yA-Y]*" ! -name "*\.gz*"`

Comment: Script works great thanks. I did get some duplicate file entry errors in dovecot log though, probably due to not using maildirlock.

Comment: The bug still hasn't been fixed unfortunately...

Comment: Any idea how to avoid the e-mail client (specifically Thunderbird), from re-downloading and re-indexing all the messages that were compressed?

Comment: I don't have this issue, make sure the name and mtime of before/after are the same (check /var/log/archived-emails.log and ls -la), since only the flag is changed, they shouldn't be considered as a different email by dovecot (which is what's happening in your case), if it's not make sure your email storage is actually maildir

Comment: The error message and reindexing are part of the same problem, which I think is this `dovecot-uidlist is updated lazily to optimize for disk I/O. If a message is expunged, it may not be removed from dovecot-uidlist until sometimes later. This means that if you create a new file using the same file name as what already exists in dovecot-uidlist, Dovecot thinks you “unexpunged” message by restoring a message from backup. This causes a warning to be logged and the file to be renamed.

`